# Lag in Ajax response

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, lag

I am sending an ajax request to a controller/action in Codeigniter and it does some manipulation and sends a response.
The response that I get is accurate but the time taken for it to send the response is 4-5 seconds which is huge.

I was able to debug and pin point the cause of this lag. At the end of the method I am sending a mail. I am using mail() function here. I am even suppressing the error by writing @mail(), so on localhost it is not giving any error and executes well on the live server.

But even though there is no error, there is lag in both the environment i.e. locally and on Live server. I am not sure what the problem is. 
Now as soon as I remove/comment out the mail() function, the response is instantaneous and lightning quick.

Please let me know what might be the issue what might be the possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PHP mail() is very limited. Try using the code igniter Email class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html